# How to hide spell check button in a custom form - Sharepoint 2013

Tags: form

Good Morning;

I am using Sharepoint 2013 OP with SPD2013.

I have made a custom form using SPD2013. I want to hide the "Spell check" icon at the top of the form. How do I do that?

Comment: Please explain more. How do you have created custom form? Where do you see the spell check option on form?

Comment: I have created a custom form using SPD2013. I upload that as a Webpart to my site gallery. Using SPD2013 I created a new .ASPX page. I inserted a Web Part Zone then inserted the Form Web Part. I want to remove the Spell Check button at the top left corner. I also am having issues with my input fields aligning with the column names on the form.

Comment: Did you try using Java script to hide the element?

Comment: I haven't been able to find one.

Comment: Are you talking about the "Spelling" option on form? given in the image: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/getfile/798906

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would guess that you have the problem with the `Spelling...` link which shows up when you have a text editor on the page. If that's the case, you can remove it by using the following javascript:

```
var d = document.querySelectorAll(".ms-toolbar");
for(var v in d) if (d[v].style) d[v].style.display = "none";
```

Please check if there is anything else on the page with the class `ms-toolbar` and make the appropriate changes to exclude it if there is.

Answer (score 0):

To hide the default Spell check option on SharePoint form, you can use either one of the below solution:

1. **Using Javascript**:  You can add the Script Editor web part on you form page and use below javascript code:

   `<script type="text/javascript"> 
   document.querySelector("li[id='Ribbon.ListForm.Edit.SpellCheck']").style.display = "none";    </script>`
2. **Using CSS**: You can add the Script Editor web part on you form page and use below CSS code:

   `<style type="text/css">  #Ribbon\.ListForm\.Edit\.SpellCheck { display: none !important }  </style>`

Comment: I tried both of these and they don't work. Hmm

Comment: Can you share the screenshot by inspecting the spelling check element from browser's developer window? That will be helpful to answer your question.